# Is there inherent interaction between odes when using matlab's ode45 function?

Tags: matlab, ode, interaction

I am trying to model interaction (diffusion) between population in two blocks using Matlab's ODE45 function. 
The population in each block is governed by the same set of ODEs, but has different initial conditions.

However, I find that even when there is no interaction term between the two blocks (such that they should be independent), the difference in initial conditions still seems to influence the populations in them. This means that, when calculated together, the populations in the blocks differ from when calculated separately. Is there an explanation for this?

I tried this with a very simple model for a proof of concept:

Function calls:

```
[t1,y1] = ode45(@equations, [1:20], [100; 50]); % block 1
[t2,y2] = ode45(@equations, [1:20], [100; 100]); % block 2
[t3,y3] = ode45(@equations2, [1:20], [100;50;100;100]); % (block 1, block 2)
```

Function modelling population in one block only:

```
function [dydt] = equations(t,y)

dydt = [(y(1) + 5*y(2)); ... %m
        (-y(2) - 2*y(1)); ... %n
       ];
return
```

Function modelling both blocks, but without interaction:

```
function [dydt] = equations2(t,y)

dydt = [(y(1) + 5*y(2)); ... %m, block 1
       (-y(2) - 2*y(1)); ... %n, block 1

       (y(3) + 5*y(4)); ... %m, block 2
       (-y(4) - 2*y(3)); ... %n, block 2
       ];
return
```

Result when two blocks calculated separately:

```
 100                50                  100                 100
-82.5651126482403   -61.2399111160678   -70.8298703784238   -113.079426303262
63.5149326478799    71.2611808361777    40.2624466444427    123.919353592460
-43.1859556122909   -79.8393860152817   -8.90683490348150   -132.277927048621
21.9743397563556    86.8220697463693    -22.6303780909040   137.973908367664
-0.354918519359671  -92.0989416214417   53.7225657700143    -140.919984325956
-21.2629138588043   95.5352361959004    -83.7315196717762   141.098469411677
42.4644938860107    -97.0482785784471   112.050303306456    -138.445708319198
-62.8212058809813   96.6327114704933    -138.138533695681   133.012881410501
81.9247177241794    -94.3111553111835   161.481224015549    -124.963465578347
-99.3812030807478   90.1082810663461    -181.603255611880   114.429891038409
114.845927928453    -84.0902243542573   198.088587603452    -101.593579579227
-128.038489201868   76.4154884940680    -210.635351405432   86.7397437298800
138.675067137440    -67.2257825991193   219.018298709806    -70.1774427449607
-146.535410253369   56.6883955999672    -223.021403427644   52.2241854879404
151.485921591776    -45.0236010893207   222.530966569364    -33.2118012943491
-153.442292768067   32.4726456791801    -217.644899082991   13.5504349990489
152.321501615162    -19.2743265017041   208.457113276080    6.36250787673260
-148.144949801383   5.68381588482233    -195.066043293572   -26.1560882959426
141.024940766196    8.01698112966525    177.792461039602    45.4369626814643
```

Result when two blocks calculated together:

```
100                 50                  100                 100
-82.5614380549815   -61.2386250164727   -70.8214933555803   -113.085294273425
63.4808523920134    71.2492107022344    40.2403909177619    123.906052225068
-43.1428254169980   -79.8465560431243   -8.86332933780633   -132.269515222896
21.9512910424390    86.8494877098212    -22.6803808332093   137.993637919124
-0.324547757386938  -92.1128384145929   53.7640196166716    -140.954822929939
-21.3110352832942   95.5328877966081    -83.7748031881502   141.094761269331
42.5230708505071    -97.0466778715188   112.116137495667    -138.418902426909
-62.8798722752104   96.6307163280550    -138.215550196187   132.992890319329
81.9803719854667    -94.2947890971016   161.559769097134    -124.926060504869
-99.4446392159052   90.0812551138450    -181.682036111080   114.372592711550
114.920836766971    -84.0716375263694   198.174987302179    -101.539954624572
-128.100385825296   76.3847285271368    -210.709163142815   86.6824352002572
138.720481894513    -67.1710769635203   219.033021842029    -70.0921219690280
-146.574502140440   56.6199063635580    -222.990477101486   52.1070327582791
151.516503440925    -44.9493339209586   222.520965582938    -33.0950981283072
-153.445319072891   32.3873778023315    -217.627693978053   13.4288556805328
152.307662312383    -19.1817679777499   208.387426508819    6.50027540164903
-148.121448302555   5.59183915228772    -194.975897304652   -26.2998808971022
140.970297553726    8.11485856302741    177.658703561865    45.5804419325655
```

Comment: Please also post the results of the three runs.

Answer (score 0):

How much different are the results? Ode45 is a method with step-size control. The computation of the local error that is used to control the step size will certainly be different (not necessarily better or worse) for the joint system. However, the resulting differences in the values should stay inside the relative and absolute tolerances used in the method, which by default are `1e-6`. Using smaller tolerances should "decouple" the two systems to an according degree.

---

PS: Up to changes in the last displayed digit, the correct result should be

```
 1 [ 100.           50.          100.          100.        ]
 2 [ -82.53524872  -61.2596255   -70.77524805 -113.11125047]
 3 [  63.41855387   71.29313918   40.13392902  123.95857849]
 4 [ -43.03253624  -79.8997202    -8.68932914 -132.32487471]
 5 [  21.7852221    86.90710777  -22.92918773  138.04268767]
 6 [  -0.101876596 -92.1750490    54.0887768  -140.997575  ]
 7 [ -21.58350797   95.59810598  -84.16577854  141.1303955 ]
 8 [  42.83689848  -97.10776622  112.55820169 -138.43848988]
 9 [ -63.23290817   96.67381387 -138.69777167  132.97573693]
10 [  82.36331078  -94.30493447  162.06130481 -124.85147371]
11 [ -99.84521116   90.04854117 -182.18117983  114.2283074 ]
12 [ 115.32870896  -83.9898257   198.6546973  -101.31886073]
13 [-128.50390187   76.2500533  -211.15213965   86.38151638]
14 [ 139.1070883   -66.98413557  219.42337049  -69.71524539]
15 [-146.92604542   56.37752991 -223.30284108   51.65362329]
16 [ 151.80427675  -44.6425276   222.71290379  -32.55815357]
17 [-153.64414443   32.0140048  -217.66536621   12.81103218]
18 [ 152.40882353  -18.74472148  208.26125485    7.1925021 ]
19 [-148.12303898    5.10026242 -194.68879305  -27.05207841]
20 [ 140.87257081    8.64627842  177.21963374   46.37020718]
```

Both your runs already differ unacceptably in the first line.

Comment: The difference is not large, but is certainly larger than 1e-6. Interestingly, when the initial condition of both blocks are the same (i.e. 100;50;100;50), the results are exactly the same as when calculated individually, which led me to wonder if some form of interaction was built in.

Comment: Could you try via the options of the ode45 method to set the tolerances to smaller values, say `1e-10` for both, and observe if the behavior changes?

Comment: I set both absolute and relative error tolerance to 1e-10, and the issue still looks to exist - only the very last few decimal places change with the change in tolerance.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your edit earlier; can you please explain how you found those values? Have I implemented ode45 incorrectly?

Comment: @anna: Using RK4 with fixed step size and checking that the decimals remain valid over a range `h, h/2, h/4` of step sizes. -- I really do not see (no matlab available to try out) what the problem is, your commands are straightforward, and ODE45 should be more precise for a result that is a combination of `sin(3*t)` and `cos(3*t)`. Perhaps you can reduce your code to the absolute necessary minimum, take away the trailing semi-colons, end your functions with `end` instead of (or additional to) `return`.

Comment: Thank you! The problem lay with the fact that I was specifying time as [1:20], which produced more convenient results for me, but forced matlab to display results with time 1,2,3.. even though it takes far smaller steps when solving. Having two different initial conditions may have affected the value chosen to be the 'solution at time t'.  If [1 20] was used, more time steps are displayed, and using a smaller tolerance as you suggest, gave consistent results between methods.

Comment: Even with the time steps given as `[1:20]`, internally an adaptive step size is used. So the display may be in steps of `1`, but internally the step size is still about the 4th or 5th root of the relative tolerance, smaller for stiff systems. The displayed results are, if I remember the documentation right, interpolated when a step passes one of those times.